# How to get newest movies on Netflix

Tags: netflix

I am using Netflix in the U.K. I know that I can go to a category and sort by newest, but is there a way to get newest movies on all over Netflix? Like sorting all movies with newest first, or maybe getting a feed with newest added movies?

Comment: Isn't there usually a category called "New Releases"?

Comment: @ai e. No I can't find something like this

Comment: @AlE. I can find it now, in fact since long time ago, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Log in an go to this page:

[www.Netflix.com/browse/new-arrivals](https://www.netflix.com/browse/new-arrivals)